# Detecting what text has been cropped from a Kivy label

Tags: kivy

I have a Kivy label that displays a lot of text, and some text is inevitably clipped (text_size is fixed). How can I determine exactly which characters are being rendered? Kivy clearly knows what words are visible (they disappear discretely as the label size changes), but I see no property or method to determine what is rendered. Ideally, I would determine how much text can be displayed before rendering, so that I only attempt to render what will fit.

For context, this is for an e-reader-like app, so I would render a page's worth of text at a time, and then display what doesn't fit on the next page.

The only way I can think to do this is to add an anchor to every word and then check which anchors exist, but this seems inefficient. It also requires me to guess how much text to try displaying, which may be hard to do reliably. Hence the desire to find a solution that doesn't require rendering first (though I understand this may not be possible, unless their is some way to access intermediate steps in the rendering process).

Comment: "Kivy clearly knows what words are visible (they disappear discretely as the label size changes)" <- the library rendering the text knows but I'm not sure this information is passed back to Kivy. I think the way to investigate would be to read Kivy's text provider code and the documentation for the providers, and see if/how this information could be made accessible.

Comment: You may be able to use `kivy,core.text.Label` to do some sort of multi-pass scheme where you set the text of the core Label and then `refresh()` and examine the resulting `content_size`. Then you can adjust how much text you include until you get an acceptable size. You can set the `text_size` of the core Label to a tuple like `(500, None)` to allow the `content_size` to be constrained horizontally.